# Cannot bundle in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I recently had to add two gems to my gem file. When I added them to my gemfile, I pushed directly to my production server.
I SSH'd into my production server, and tried running *bundle install*. This is the error I go:

```
>> bundle install
```

.........

```
>> You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the Gemfile freeze 
by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.

You have added to the Gemfile:
* RedCloth
* tanker
```

Comment: The answer you're looking for is in the error message itself. Do bundle install in development machine and push **also** the Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add gems to your Gemfile, you MUST bundle in your dev environment **before** pushing and deploying.